# When I want to get data from the database I encountered error 500

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, backend

When I want to get data from the database and using this code:

```
public ActionResult GetSkills()
{
    var Skills = DataBase.Table_DoctorSkills
                         .Select(x => new {x.ID, x.DoctorSkills})
                         .ToList();

    return Json(Skills, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It's ok and this code works, but when I am using this code:

```
public ActionResult GetSkills()
{
    var Skills = DataBase.Table_DoctorSkills.ToList();
    return Json(Skills, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I encounter an error 500.

I don't know why - I want to get the list of the whole database at once.

What can I do?

Comment: Make sure to properly set up some kind of exception handling and logging so that you can view the actual exception that caused your error. Without this information no one can tell you what goes wrong. If you are debugging look in your console for the exception.

Comment: did you call this method via jQuery Ajax?